# Merging two dictionaries into a dictionary of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, collections

I've got a default dictionary from collections library which rapresents the list of all the connections of each node of a graph:

```
edges = {1 : [987, 682, 465], 
         2 : [45, 67, 85, 907, ...],
         ...
         n : [32, 563, 659, 902]}
```

And I've got another one that stores for each node the category from which it belongs like this:

```
categories = {1 : ['category1', 'category37'], 
              2 : ['category45', 'category86', ...],
             ... , 
              n : ['category1','category2'], ....}
```

I would like to obtain a final dictionary that contins for each category the dictionary of all the connection of that category, it would look like this:

```
final = {'category1' : {1 : [987, 682, 465], 37: [84, 777, 90, 744, 343], ...},
         'category2' : {37 : [84, 777, 90, 744, 343], 64: [32, 1222], ...}
          ...}
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Using Pyhton3 .

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: `final = {}

for key in categories:

    for i in categories[key]:

        final[i][key].append(edges[key])`

But this raises an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nested loops to accomplish that.

One line version:

```
final = {category: {edge: edges[edge]} for edge in edges \
         for category in categories[edge] if category in categories[edge]}
```

Detailed version with clear steps:

```
final = {}
for edge in edges:  # loop through each edge
    # find all categories that belong to the current edge in outer loop and then append 
    # the edge list to the corresponding category in the final dictionary
    for category in categories[edge]:
        if category in final:
            final[category][edge] = edges[edge]
        else:
            final[category] = {edge: edges[edge]}
```

To test this, I have made up an example.

```
edges = {1:[11,56,3], 2:[69,4,5,6], 3:[1,8,96,5]}
categories = {1:['category1', 'category37'],2:['category45', 'category86'],3:['category1','category2']}
```

The result is

```
{'category1': {1: [11, 56, 3], 3: [1, 8, 96, 5]},
 'category37': {1: [11, 56, 3]},
 'category45': {2: [69, 4, 5, 6]},
 'category86': {2: [69, 4, 5, 6]},
 'category2': {3: [1, 8, 96, 5]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The task can be accomplished as follows:

1. Create an intermediate dictionay whose keys are
   the categories: `categoryX`, and values are a list of the edges that fall under `categoryX`
2. Create the final dictionary whoes keys are the categories: `categoryX` and corresponding values are
   the dictionary of edges that fall under `categoryX`

We use the builtin defaultdict to ease the creation of the intermediate dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict


edges = {1 : [987, 682, 465],
         2 : [45, 67, 85, 907],
         3 : [32, 563, 659, 902]}

categories = {1 : ['category1', 'category37'],
              2 : ['category45', 'category86'],
              3 : ['category1', 'category2']}

intermediate = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in categories.items():
    for c in v:
        intermediate[c].append(k)


final = defaultdict(dict)

for k, v in intermediate.items():
    final[k] = {i:edges[i] for i in v}
```

We can also create `final` with a list comprehension as follows:

```
last = {k: {i : edges[i] for i in v} for k, v in intermediate.items()}
```

Sample run:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(final)
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {'category1': {1: [987, 682, 465], 3: [32, 563, 659, 902]},
             'category2': {3: [32, 563, 659, 902]},
             'category37': {1: [987, 682, 465]},
             'category45': {2: [45, 67, 85, 907]},
             'category86': {2: [45, 67, 85, 907]}})

>>> pprint(last)
{'category1': {1: [987, 682, 465], 3: [32, 563, 659, 902]},
 'category2': {3: [32, 563, 659, 902]},
 'category37': {1: [987, 682, 465]},
 'category45': {2: [45, 67, 85, 907]},
 'category86': {2: [45, 67, 85, 907]}}
```

Using an intermedeate table is a great way to do things like searching through a complex dataset/table in a flexible way, linking tables, and creating new tables easily.

Comment: raises a key error on the first value of the edge dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Python `dict` do not have `.append()` method (but `list`), what you want is `.update()`

If you want to use for-loop, you can try

```
# Example using for-loop
edges = {
    1: [1, 11], 
    2: [2, 222], 
    3: [33], 
    4: [4, 4444, 44]}
categories = {
    1: ['category1'], 
    2: ['category2', 'category3'], 
    3: ['category1', 'category4']}

final = {} 
for key, value in categories.items():
    final['category{}'.format(key)] = {}
    for x in value:
        edge_key = int(x.replace('category', ''))
        final['category{}'.format(key)].update({edge_key: edges[edge_key]})
>>> print(final)
# Output
# {'category2': {2: [2, 222], 3: [33]}, 'category1': {1: [1, 11]}, 'category3': {1: [1, 11], 4: [4, 4444, 44]}}
```

Comment: Raises this error: 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10'.

Comment: @PaoloG. What is your `edges` and `categories`? I don't get any error running my codes.

Comment: Hi @kitman0804, [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KETLNZk3J1-lYNnehY5BZG_QYRLMvOqU/view?usp=sharing) is how my "edges" dictionary looks like. And [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lt2kdH4CkAhiaqUcYA7w_2-QcK2deyQN/view?usp=sharing) is how my "categories" dictionary looks like.

Comment: @PaoloG. Your data is not the same as the example data you provided, that's why you get errores. How you link 'English_footballers', ... to the keys in `edges`?